How to show that the following representation is indecomposable?
Let $A:=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal of all homogeneous polynomials of degree $\geq 2$. Let $V=A^*$ be the space of all linear functionals on $A$ with the agtion given by $(\rho(a)f)(b)=f(ba)$ for $a,b\in A$ and $f\in A^*$. I want to show that $V$ is indecomposable.
Our definition of indecomposable is that $V$ cannot be written as a direct sum of two nonzero subrepresentations.
I did the following. First let me remark that by definition of $I_2$ we deduce that $A=span(1,x,y)$, so $\dim(A)=3$ and hence $\dim(V)=3$. Let me define a basis for $V$ by $\{f_1,f_x,f_y\}$ where $f_1(a+bx+cy)=a$, $f_x(a+bx+cy)=b$ and $f_y(a+bx+cy)=c$. Now I wanted to assume that $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ where $V_1,V_2$ are two nonzero subrepresentations. Since by definition $V_1\cap V_2=\{0\}$ we can w.l.o.g. assume that $V_1=span(f_1)$ and $V_2=span(f_x,f_y)$. By definition of a subrepresentation we additionally know that for any $g_1\in V_1$ and $g_2\in V_2$ we have $$\rho(a)g_1\in V_1, \rho(a)g_2\in V_2,$$ for any $a\in A$. Now I don't see how to continue and get a contradiction. What I know is that $\rho(x)f_1=0$ and $\rho(y)f_1=0$. But I don't see how to continue, can someone help me futher?

This should really be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to add comments yet.
You should specify over which $\mathbb{C}$-algebra you are considering your respresentations, here it is $A = \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ itself. Also, I suspect you are coming from Problem 2.5.2(c) in Etingof et al.'s Introduction to Representation Theory - if so please add this to your question.
Hint: Can you show that $A$ itself is an indecomposable representation of $A$? What does this tell you about the dual representation $A^*$?

Thanks for your answer. If $A$ is indecomposable of itself, then $A^*$ also is an indecomposable representation right? But which representation do I use for $A$?

@user123234 Subrepresentations of $A$ over itself are ideals. So you have to show that $A$ is not a direct sum of ideals. One way of approaching this is the Chinese Remainder Theorem, or you can show that any ideal containing a polynomial with nonzero constant term is already the entire $A$.
